# Using Advanced Lookup Functions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, worksheet-function

So, I have this workbook consisting of Summary:Temperatures by Month.
There are two worksheets with Summary - High Temp and Summary - Low Temp.
The Summary High Temp Worksheet looks like this:

```
City/State/Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr
{[ColB]/[ColC]/[ColD]/[ColE]/[ColF]/[ColG]}
R5: A/AA/30/32/40/42
R6: B/BB/32/34/41/43
R7: C/CC/38/36/44/45
R8: D/DD/40/39/47/49
```

Now, I have to retrieve data for "**CITY-WIDE HIGH TEMPERATURES BY MONTH**" from Summary High Temp Worksheet into another worksheet that is currently in this format:

```
City/High Temp
{[ColJ]/[ColI]}
R5:A/ _________
R6:B/ _________
R7:C/ _________
R8:D/ _________
```

Moreover, I have drop-down list with Month Names and Month Numbers like these:

```
Month:Mar
[Cell:B3/C3]
Month Number: 3
[Cell:J2/K2]
```

[The drop-downs are dynamic in nature. So for instance, if I select Mar in Month it will give me 5 in Month Number etc]

How, can I make use of the above list in my formula to retrieve temperatures for the **specified city and month**?

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Answer (score 0):

the are 2 easy ways to do this

1) make a cheat column that is city+month combined so you have a unike identifier  so in a new column you could reefer  to firhst the month locked in line 1 and then the city in different lines  (=$B$1&C2 and then drag down)

2) since you only have one unike value pr city/mont/high or low you could do a "MAXIFS"  where you specify city + month as criteria

Comment: Can't we use any of the Advanced Lookup Functions (INDIRECT, ADDRESS, MATCH) here?

Comment: sure you can, this is just an easy fix, that is easy to remember :)  (if its simple and it works, use it ;)  )

Comment: Yeah. Can you also tell me how? I have tried using INDEX but the values won't update across for other months....

Comment: i avoid index match if i can, so im not good at using it... try" maxifs" it is very easy to use. if you upload an example file i can show you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `INDEX-MATCH` to accomplish this, it can be done by utilizing `HLOOKUP-MATCH` to retrieve a value at an intersection point. I recreated a basic layout of your data and in `J5` used

```
=HLOOKUP($B$3,'Summary - High Temp '!$B$4:$G$8,MATCH(I5,'Summary - High Temp '!$B$4:$B$8,0),FALSE)
```

Where `$B$3` is a reference to your drop down list of month names, `'Summary - High Temp '!$B$4:$G$8` is reference to your high temp data array, `I5` is a reference to the City being searched for and `'Summary - High Temp '!$B$4:$B$8` is a reference to the column containing the array of city names.

This would allow you to select any month from your drop down list and your search values would update. This, of course, assumes you only have one temperature value for each unique City-Month.